# Mapstruct mapping Boolean to String

Tags: java, string, boolean, mapping, mapstruct

I have several `Boolean` fields in my model class (source). The target field in my DTO class is `String`. I need to map `true` as `Y` and `false` as `N`. There are more than 20 `Boolean` fields and right now I am using 20+ `@Mapping` annotation with `expression` option, which is overhead. There must be a simple way or solution that I am not aware. Can anyone help to simplify this?

I am using `mapstruct` version `1.2.0.Final`

**Source.java**

```
class Source{
  private Boolean isNew;
  private Boolean anyRestriction;
  // several Boolean fields
}
```

**Target.java**

```
class Target{
  private String isNew;
  private String anyRestriction;
}
```

**Helper.java**

```
class Helper{
  public String asString(Boolean b){
    return b==null ? "N" : (b ? "Y" : "N");
  }
}
```

**MyMapper.java**

```
@Mapper interface MyMapper{
  @Mappings(
    @Mapping(target="isNew", expression="java(Helper.asString(s.isNew()))"
    // 20+ mapping like above, any simple way ? 
  )
  Target map(Source s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I needed. Just wanted to point out that your expression will need fully qualified package name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analogous to [Map Struct Reference#Invoking Other Mappers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers), you can define (your Helper) class like:

```
public class BooleanYNMapper {

    public String asString(Boolean bool) {
        return null == bool ?
            null : (bool ? 
                "Y" : "N"
            );
    }

    public Boolean asBoolean(String bool) {
        return null == bool ?
            null : (bool.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith("y") ?
                Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
            );
    }
}
```

..and then use it in (the hierarchy of) your mappers:

```
@Mapper(uses = BooleanYNMapper.class)
interface MyMapper{
    Target map(Source s);
    //and even this will work:
    Source mapBack(Target t);
}
```

Comment: Please consider/adjust in your implementation: This accepts (&reflects) nulls, and only strings *starting with (ignore case)* `y` are considered `true` all others as `false`;)

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, you just have to provide a custom type conversion concrete method.
Let's say you're still using abstract classes for Mappers.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class YourMapper {
    @Mappings(...)
    public abstract Target sourceToTarget(final Source source);

    public String booleanToString(final Boolean bool) {
        return bool == null ? "N" : (bool ? "Y" : "N");
    }
}
```

This should be possible even with Java 8 Interface default methods.

Comment: Yes you can do this with a default method or even a default static method on the interface

Comment: Both the answers are working. I accepted @xerx593’s as correct because I can reuse the BooleanYNMapper in some other mapper interface. Thanks.